# Что не так с Gulp?

Tags: gulp

Я только знакомлюсь с Gulp. Мне интересно разобраться в причине.

Пользуюсь редактором кода VS Code, решила установить Gulp. Скачала Node JS и установила нужные пакеты в терминале редактора кода. Эврика! css компилируется в scss. Пока открыт редактор, сайт всё отображает корректно. Когда я закрываю редактор, то вся вёрстка ломается. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что не так?

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const sass = require('gulp-sass');
const sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
const watch = require('gulp-watch');

gulp.task('sass-compile', function() {
    return gulp.src('./scss/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./css/'))
})

gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('app/scss/**/*.scss', gulp.series('sass-compile'));
});
```

```
{
  "name": "project-3",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "gulp-cli": "^2.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^4.0.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^2.6.5",
    "gulp-watch": "^5.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Comment: У вас ничего не запускается в IDE (редактор) пока вы работаете с проектом?

Comment: VS Code мой текущий редактор. Не работает сайт в браузере, когда я выхожу из редактора

Comment: вопрос решили этот ?

Answer (score 1):

Вы запускаете из среды разработки (VS Code) и Gulp и локальный сервер с сайтом (команда `go live server`), поэтому при закрытии IDE у вас перестает работать сайт. Чтобы сайт в браузере продолжал работать после того, как вы закрыли IDE - необходимо запускать Gulp не в IDE и добавить запуск дев-сервера из `gulpfile`.

Чтобы в браузере открылась веб-страница, нужен локальный сервер. Достаточно доставить пакет [`gulp-webserver`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-webserver) (команда `npm install --save-dev gulp-webserver`) и немного модернизировать `gulpfile`:

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const sass = require('gulp-sass');
const sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
const watch = require('gulp-watch');
const webserver = require('gulp-webserver');

gulp.task('webserver', function() {
  gulp.src('app')
    .pipe(webserver({
      livereload: true,
      directoryListing: true,
      open: true
    }));
});

gulp.task('sass-compile', function() {
    return gulp.src('./scss/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./css/'))
})

gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('app/scss/**/*.scss', gulp.series('sass-compile'));
});

gulp.task('default', gulp.parallel('webserver', 'watch'));
```

После этого зайти через консоль (я использую Git Bash, но можно и через CMD) в каталог, содержащий `gulpfile` и `package.json`, и оттуда выполнить команду запуска Gulp через команду `gulp`. На экране должно появиться что-то вроде следующей картины (запуск через `gulp` - запускает задачу по-умолчанию, она же `default`):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так как у вас уже висит вотчер на определенных типах файлов, то при изменении и сохранении файлов в любом редакторе, изменения должны отобразиться в консоли при сборке, а также и в запущенном сайте. Также, при закрытии IDE, не будет останавливаться сайт, только при закрытии консоли и остановке запущенного в ней процесса будет останавливаться сайт.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91873/discussion-on-answer-by-denis-bubnov-----gulp).

Comment: Извиняюсь, случайно, вместо перенесения комментариев в чат преобразовал ответ в комментарий( Спасибо, что обратили внимание на мою неточность)

Comment: Почему-то не было возможности создать чат. Даже не смотря на большое количество комментариев. Спасибо, что оперативно ответили)

Comment: Пожалуйста) Наверное что-то в движке сайта глюкануло)